# is creating model from another model and copying its value considered as good practices?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, postgresql, database-design

lets says I have `inventory` model and `inventory_transaction` model which contain `inventory_id` and `inventory_transfer` model which contain many `inventory_transaction` and has one `branch target`

then inside the inventory transfer I have this method which create item model

```
  def create_item(user_id)
    self.decrement_inventory_transactions.each do |entry|
      item = Item.includes(:inventory_transaction).where(branch_id: self.branch_id).where("inventory_transaction.inventory_id": entry.inventory_id).first
      if item
        self.increment_item_transactions.create!(
          item: item,
          approved_at: DateTime.current,
          approved_by_id: user_id,
          quantity: entry.quantity
        )
      else
        Item.create!(branch_id: self.branch_id, inventory_transaction_id: entry.id)
      end
    end
  end
```

see in this code if there is no `item` with the particular `inventory id` then create the `item` if the `item` with that particular `inventory_id` is exist then create `increment_item_transaction` by copying the quantity from the `inventory_transfer` qty

my `schema.rb`

```
  create_table "inventories", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.bigint "receive_order_entry_id", null: false
    t.decimal "price_base", default: "0.0", null: false
    t.decimal "price_sell", default: "0.0", null: false
  end

  create_table "inventory_transactions", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.bigint "inventory_id", null: false
    t.integer "quantity", default: 0, null: false
    t.string "inventory_transaction_header_type", null: false
    t.bigint "inventory_transaction_header_id", null: false
    t.string "type"
    t.datetime "approved_at"
    t.bigint "approved_by_id"
  end

  create_table "inventory_transfers", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.bigint "item_request_id"
    t.bigint "user_id", null: false
    t.bigint "cabang_id", null: false
    t.bigint "received_by_id"
    t.datetime "received_at"
    t.bigint "approved_by_id"
  end

  create_table "items", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.bigint "inventory_transaction_id", null: false
    t.bigint "branch_id", null: false
  end


  create_table "item_transactions", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.bigint "item_id", null: false
    t.integer "quantity", default: 0, null: false
    t.string "type"
    t.datetime "approved_at"
    t.bigint "approved_by_id"
    t.string "item_transaction_header_type", null: false
    t.bigint "item_transaction_header_id", null: false
    t.decimal "transaction_price", default: "0.0", null: false
  end
```

Comment: Is it a good practice? No not really. Do ppl do it? Yes. When you have two objects interacting like this there is a always a problem in defining responsibility of each class and you're very likely overburdoning the model. An alternative is to use the service objects pattern or interactors.

Comment: that is kinda new words to me any guidance how to learn more about that? the `service objects pattern` and `interactors`?

Comment: https://blog.appsignal.com/2020/06/17/using-service-objects-in-ruby-on-rails.html

Comment: https://mkdev.me/en/posts/a-couple-of-words-about-interactors-in-rails#:~:text=Interactor%20is%20a%20service%20object,business%20logic%20of%20the%20application.